# When do I have to use たくさん and とても?

Tags: grammar

I don't know when I have to use *totemo* and *takusan*. They both mean "very", don't they?

Comment: What made you think たくさん means "very"? Can you give an example where たくさん is used as "very"?

Answer (score 5):

> They both mean "very", don't they?

No, while とても means "very", たくさん does not.

- たくさん is an adjective, means "a lot of", or "plenty of", and you use it generally for describing noun quantity.

  E.g. たくさんのお金{かね} = a lot of money
- とても is an adverb modifying adjectives.

  E.g. とてもうれしい = very glad

Both words are used similarly to their English counterparts.

Comment: In addition, たくさん can be used adverbially like 彼女とたくさん話したい(I want to talk with her a lot).

Comment: In addition, you can say 私｛わたし｝は「とても」「たくさん」本｛ほん｝を持｛も｝っている。I have tremendously a lot of books.

Comment: @YuuichiTam I can't see how your example is adverbial. You don't say "I want it a lot"

Comment: @mackygoo I don't understand the intention behind your comment. Do you mind explaining?

Comment: @macraf たくさん話す and たくさん走る are natural phrase. This たくさん modifies a verb(they are 話す and 走る in this case), so this たくさん is used adverbially.

Comment: @YuuichiTam Ok, seems that the scope of adverbial phrases is more broad than I originally thought. Still as a word たくさん is an adjective even though it can be used adverbially. Not sure if I need to correct my answer, as I see no difference between the usage in English and Japanese.

Comment: たくさん走る means "to run a lot". This "a lot" is an adverb, isn't it? How much did you run? I ran a lot.

Comment: I don't think you are replying to my latest comment.

Comment: たくさん is defined by goo dictionary as a na-adjective and a noun, and it says it is used adverbially. However I think it is important to learn the usage than to apply it to a part of speech.

Comment: @macraf >Do you mind explaining? I wanted to show you an very interesting example using　「とても」　and 「たくさん」　in a same sentence. 私わたしはとてもたくさん本｛ほん｝を持｛も｝っている。 The meaning of the sentence is: I have a tremendously lot of books. We Japanese often use 「とてもたくさん」 to emphasize 「たくさん」. By the way, I should have shown you the  sentence like this; 私はとてもたくさん「の」本｛ほん｝を持｛も｝っている, because 本 is noun. Thank you!

Comment: @mackygoo I think  you shouldn't change your example because the one before changing is more common.

Comment: @mackygoo I just want to say that たくさん is often used adverbially and たくさん本をもっている is more common than たくさんの本を持っている. I think this information is helpful for Japanese learners. Not I want to discuss but add the information.

Comment: @ Yuuichi Tam Thank you for your information about　たくさん本をもっている。 I know たくさん本をもっている is more common than たくさんの本をもっている。 If I think the sentences deeply, 本をたくさんもっている　and たくさんの本を持っている are both grammatically correct Japanese. But because the both sentences have the same meaning we combined them to たくさん本をもっている。　And now the expression has become more common. – mackygoo 8 mins ago